Is there a way to simplifies NX Angular architecture?
We've implemented for few months NX in our Angular app. We really appreciate the benefits, however I think the architecture is far too deep for the libs:
|_ front
|  |_ ...
|  |_ apps
|  |  |_ myApp
|  |  |  |_ ...
|  |  |  |_ src
|  |  |  |  |_ app
|  |  |  |  |_ assets
|  |  |  |  |_ ...
|  |_ libs
|  |  |_ features
|  |  |  |_ component-A
|  |  |  |  |_ ...
|  |  |  |  |_ src
|  |  |  |  |  |_ ...
|  |  |  |  |  |_ i18n
|  |  |  |  |  |_ lib
|  |  |  |  |  |  |_ ...
|  |  |  |  |  |  |_ modals
|  |  |  |  |  |  |_ pages
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |_ ...
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |_ page
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |_ index.ts
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |_ page.component.html
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |_ page.component.scss
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |_ page.component.ts
|  |  |_ shared

My question : would it be possible to remove lib and src directories and flatten a bit the architecture without compromising the benefits of NX ?

It's possible, you need to adjust paths at various places but it works.
